# How to rounds down date filter query using spring data solr?

Tags: java, spring, solr, solrj, spring-data-solr

How can I rounds down date filter query using spring data solr?

I want to write query `fq=startDate:[2013-06-14T23:59:59.999Z/DAY TO 2013-06-14T23:59:59.999Z/DAY]` using `FilterQuery`.

How can I rounds down following query using `FilterQuery` ?

```
FilterQuery filterQuery = new SimpleFilterQuery();
filterQuery.addCriteria(new Criteria(EventDocument.FIELD_START_DATE).between(sc.getStartDate(), sc.getStartDate()));
```

Any Hint will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest would probably be to use `SimpleStringCriteria`

```
String start = JavaDateConverter.INSTANCE.convert(sc.getStartDate())+"/DAY";
String end = JavaDateConverter.INSTANCE.convert(sc.getEndDate())+"/DAY";
Criteria criteria = new SimpleStringCriteria("[" + start + " TO " + end + "]");
```

A bit more complex is registering a custom converter

```
@Configuration
@EnableSolrRepositories
public class SolrContext {

  //..skipped solr server initialization to shorten

  @Bean
  public SolrTemplate solrTemplate() throws Exception {
    SolrTemplate solrTemplate = new SolrTemplate(solrServerFactory());
    solrTemplate.setSolrCore("collection1"); 
    solrTemplate.registerQueryParser(SimpleQuery.class, queryParser());
    return solrTemplate;
  }

  @Bean  
  public QueryParser queryParser() {
    DefaultQueryParser queryParser = new DefaultQueryParser();

    //register custom converter for Date
    queryParser.registerConverter(RoundDayConverter.INSTANCE);
    return queryParser;
  }

  private enum RoundDayConverter implements Converter<Date, String> {
    INSTANCE;

    private static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime().withZoneUTC();

    @Override
    public String convert(Date source) {
      if (source == null) {
        return "";
      }

      return ClientUtils.escapeQueryChars(FORMATTER.print(source.getTime())) + "/DAY";
    }
  }
}
```

As the above would apply to every `Date` it might be a good idea to create a custom type and register a converter for that.